# Adding ArcGIS Online Webmap to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, arcgis-online

I am very new to QGIS and I am wondering is there a way to add this map to  QGIS.

The map can be found on:
https://glasgowgis.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=8eb9f600ed154ae58b09c2c5902ce7f0.

Comment: That's not a web map, that's a web application.  However, it does include a webmap, and if you can find the URL for that web map, it may be feasible.  But it appears they don't publish any webmaps directly via their 'gallery', so there is no easy way to find the webmap URL.

Comment: Adding to that...the Web Application is owned by GlasgowGIS. I have searched through the Feature Services owned and published by GlasgowGIS in the ArcGIS "Add Information from AGOL" feature in ArcMap and I cannot see anything relating to the AtOM Cycling Information Web Map there. There area few feature services published by them, so they may have a feature service to publish. I think it best if you contact GlasgowGIS and see if there is a way to get access to that information.

Comment: The data is available but is a 'hack' please seek permission > contact location@glasgow.gov.uk

Answer (score 1):

The basemap is available in QGIS

Using the **ArcGIS Mapserver** connector in QGIS

Then add the url

> `https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/7a9ed8a468534a76818604815f2e259c/rest/services/AGOL/BaseMapping/MapServer/`

[image]

For the Featureserver your out of luck without a user/password or api token.

contact location@glasgow.gov.uk